# How to edit html template code embedded in a Typescript file in Atom

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript, atom-editor

It seems the trend with Angular development is to embed the template code in the Angular component which is typically a Typescript or Javascript file.

If I try to do that I (understandably) don't get html syntax highlighting. Is there a way to fix that in Atom, or another editor?

Answer (score 0):

I am using [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) and it supports the inline HTML template highlight. (I think Webstorm and other products might too)

[image: HTML syntax-highlight in intellij idea inside .ts file]